# sphinx autosummary and dynamic methods

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have found much use of using  `setattr()` to make dynamically generated class methods and attributes. I have also been using sphinx to create documentation, which is fantastic.

The problem is that i cannot use the autosummary feature of sphinx if the attributes and methods are dynamic. Is there a clever way to do this? The dynamic methods and attributes are created upon initialization.

Comment: Are you setting the ``__doc__`` property of the dynamic methods?

Comment: yes, so their documentation works when using the help() command, but sphinx doesnt include them in the autoclass because the methods are generated until the class is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it's a little wacky):

1. Create an instance of your class in your `conf.py` file.
2. Use the [autodoc-process-docstring](http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-docstring) event to fire a handler (which you will need to write) to copy the `__doc__` elements for the various dynamic methods from the instance you created in 1) into the output for the class.

It's not a simple solution, nor easy, and heck, maybe not even possible, but it Just Might Work if you can figure out how to get things to happen at thw right time.